# Using Async/Await with Bluebird's `catch` filtered variants

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, sequelize.js, bluebird

Bluebird describes its `Promise` monkey patch of `catch` as having a "filtered variant" described as follows:

> This is an extension to .catch to work more like catch-clauses in languages like Java or C#. Instead of manually checking instanceof or .name === "SomeError", you may specify a number of error constructors which are eligible for this catch handler. The catch handler that is first met that has eligible constructors specified, is the one that will be called.

And the given example is:

```
somePromise.then(function() {
    return a.b.c.d();
}).catch(TypeError, function(e) {
    //If it is a TypeError, will end up here because
    //it is a type error to reference property of undefined
}).catch(ReferenceError, function(e) {
    //Will end up here if a was never declared at all
}).catch(function(e) {
    //Generic catch-the rest, error wasn't TypeError nor
    //ReferenceError
});
```

In [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/getting-started.html), which has a Bluebird dependency and uses Bluebird promises, the suggested method (as far as I'm aware anyway) for catching query errors, such as validation errors when creating a new record, is to utilize the Bluebird filtered variant of `catch`.

Here is my example of catching a `Sequelize.ValidationError`:

```
models.User.create(params).then(function(user) {
  // do something with user
}).catch(Sequelize.ValidationError, function (err) {
  var error = err.errors[0],
      message = error ? error.message : "Invalid parameters.";

  return res.send(422, { message : message });
}).catch(function(err) {
  next(err);
});
```

I like this. It allows me to handle a validation error differently (respond with `422` and the error) than other general errors I might otherwise want to bubble up to my general error catcher that responds with `500`.

Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, I will be unable to do this if I want to use async/await with ES6...

```
try {
    var user = await models.User.create(params);

    // do something with user
} catch (err) {
    next(err);
}
```

Is there any way, or any patterns common in the node community (I'm a little new) to do something roughly similar to the standard Promise based Sequelize/Bluebird approach to catching and handling specific types of errors using async/await?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to patch `try/catch` behavior (like you can with `.catch()` so I don't think there's any way to alter the behavior of `catch`.